# Displaying small svg pictures in html tags

Tags: html, svg

I would like an SVG picture of a triangle inside a `<div>` tag. I would like it to appear at the top of the `<div>` tag. I tried this:

```html
    <div style='width:20px;height:10px;background-color:blue'>
      <svg width="20px" 
           height="10px" 
           version="1.1" 
           viewBox='0 0 20 10' 
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <polygon points="0 10, 20 10, 10 0" 
                 fill="black" 
                 stroke-width="0"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

But the triangle is displayed lower than it should be. What is weird is that if I multiply by 3 every coordinate/size in the above code, then everything is displayed correctly. I tried it in codepen with Chrome/Firefox/Edge and it is the same behavior everywhere.

My question is : Am I misusing something somewhere, or is there a bug in displaying small SVG pictures ?

Comment: Try: `svg{display:block;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `display:flex` to your div:

```html
    <div style='width:20px;height:10px;background-color:blue;display:flex;'>
      <svg width="20px" 
           height="10px" 
           version="1.1" 
           viewBox='0 0 20 10' 
           xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <polygon points="0 10, 20 10, 10 0" 
                 fill="black" 
                 stroke-width="0"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you know why ?

Comment: While I have no idea why the smaller size doesn't work as the bigger size (as I tried like you mentioned 3 times bigger sizes of div and svg and it was fine)(Maybe someone else could answer this), the `flex` make everything in the given element flexible - fit inside. It is used for changing what is displayed inside an element - the flow of the children inside an element. Without it, if not mistaken, the div is considered `block` element which is just to set the page flow and not what is inside it.